# .htaccess modrewrite encoding # character

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect traffic using .htaccess and it is encoding the # character in the rewrite rule, I thought that maybe the B tag would fix it but it doesn't. I don't have control over the url and when it is encoded it gives a 404 error.

How would I make sure that the # doesn't get encoded to %23 in the URL?

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule (.*) "https://somesite.com/cp/#/1234/all/app" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I wonder what this is meant to achieve... You really have a tag in your page with label "/1234/all/app"? Did't even know that was possible...

Comment: @arkascha it's not my URL and I have no control over how it functions. It just didn't function with encoding. Didn't create the problem, just had to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `NE` flag to change this encoding behavior.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^ https://somesite.com/cp/#/1234/all/app [R=301,NE,L]
```

This is assuming your code is running on some other domain other than `somesite.com`.

Comment: Thanks! - By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for example, will be converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE] flag prevents that from happening.